# psutil: get cpu of all processes

Tags: python, python-2.7, psutil

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I can't figure out how to get `current_process.cpu_percent(interval=0.1)` for all processes at once without iterating over them. Currently iteration will take `process_count * interval` seconds to finish. Is there a way around this?

So far I'm doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import psutil

cpu_count = psutil.cpu_count()

processes_info = []
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'username', 'memory_info', 'cpu_percent', 'name'])

        current_process = psutil.Process(pid=pinfo['pid'])

        pinfo["cpu_info"] = current_process.cpu_percent(interval=0.1)
        processes_info.append(pinfo)

    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        pass

print processes_info
```

As far as I understand it, I cannot include `cpu-percent` into the `attr`-list, since the help states

> When interval is 0.0 or None compares system CPU times elapsed since last call or module import, returning immediately. That means the first time this is called it will return a meaningless 0.0 value which you are supposed to ignore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to calculate CPU% you necessarily have to wait.
You don't have to wait 0.1 secs **for each process/iteration** though. 
Instead, iterate over all processes, call cpu_percent() with interval=0,  ignore the return value then wait 0.1 secs (or more). 
The second time you iterate over all processes cpu_percent(interval=0) will return a meaningful value.

Comment: It seems that this solution works like a parallel measurement. This solution reduces time from `process_count * interval`  to `interval`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of measuring CPU time of each process, so, you cannot avoid `process_count * interval` seconds in a single Python interpreter process. Maybe, you could reduce the time by means of multiprocessing.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html